# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Tags: java, json, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm using `org.json.JSONObject` to pass the parameters to the server. And I'm using Eclipse IDE. I have already added the `java-json.jar` file to the build path of the project. but still I'm getting the below exception while running the code and no compilation error is displayed. I did clean the project and refreshed several times but still I end up with exception. is there anything missing?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
```

Comment: Add the jar also to the classpath in your laucher.

Comment: You also need to add the jar intro the project's lib folder: for WAR in WEB-INF/lib and for EAR in lib.

Answer (score 3):

Download the Json jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list) and add it to the classpath. If its a web application then add its under lib's.

Comment: Thank you but it's ok to use the existing java-json.jar file

Answer (score 2):

I have added the same `java-json.jar` file to the Run configuration's class path of the particular java file. And now it's working absolutely fine. thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add maven dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```